# Bootstrap parallel - form allignment

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have two forms and I want to have them in parallel. I.e I want to split the window in two parts and put a form in each of them.

Also I want to keep elements of a block in center. I am trying with the code below. The screen got split and the elements are in desired section. But are not getting centered. `Text0` and `Button0` are part of same form and all others are part of another form.

Also please suggest me how can I use class form-group to group form elements. As here different elements of a form part in different rows. And each row has elements of both forms.

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" id="Text0" class="form-control"  placeholder = "Text" />
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="center-block">
        <select id="Select0" class="form-control col-md-6" style="width:auto;">
          <option value="1">V1</option>
          <option value="2">V2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="center-block">
      <input id="Button0" type="button" value="B0" class="btn btn-success btn-md col-md-6" style="width:auto;" onclick="b0Clicked();" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="center-block">
      <input id="Button1" type="button" value="B1" class="btn btn-success btn-md col-md-6" style="width:auto;" onclick="b1Clicked();" />
      <input id="Button2" type="button" value="B2" class="btn btn-primary btn-md col-md-6" style="width:auto;" onclick="b2clicked();" /> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle...

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks for response. But I don't understand what exactly you are asking. Sorry I have started programming recently.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/, create a demo here...save it...and post back the url...welcome to the world of programming mate!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor here it is buddy: https://jsfiddle.net/oynkw3hv/1/      you may need tobexpand the result section a bit to see the proper result of col-md-6 class

Comment: mate...your design is pretty messed up...`Text0` and `Button0` are part of same form, then why place them is separate `row`? Also, where is `form` attribute? are you suggesting that class `form-control` has to be treated as `form` here?

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks. I am keeping them in separate row as I want to keep one below other, and I want to keep the two forms side-by-side, please expand the result section of jfiddle, then you might get better idea of what I want. And if I keep them in same row they appear side-by-side. Is there another way to do that? No I am not suggesting that class form-control to be treated as form. I want to have Text0 and Button0 in same form(i.e they only are related to each other, so I want to have action like till Text0 is empty Button0 is inactive) and similarly all other elements make up another form.

Comment: still not sure but something like this? => https://jsfiddle.net/oynkw3hv/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may or may not have understood your question completely, so I am hoping this is what you are looking for. My [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKydeK) has two forms parallel to each other using Bootstrap classes and some small time css.

After inspecting your JFiddle code, I just realized you grasp the concept of Bootstraping, but you just need organization and understanding how to map your page.

The demo will show you some critical concepts that will help you get these forms to act independently meanwhile side by side.

p.s remember to always start with `col-xs-*` classes first. Bootstrap is a phone first framework.

oh and, since you are new to this, Jfiddle is good but CodePen is way better ;)